# Does Cloud Dataproc support high availability?

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I am concerned that having a single master node for a [Google Cloud Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc) cluster may introduce a single point of failure. I'd like my cluster to be (more) resilient in the case of an unexpected master failure.

Is it possible to configure my Cloud Dataproc cluster so it uses some form of *high availability* to de-risk the event of a single master failure? Ideally I'd also like to use standard methods for YARN/Hadoop/HDFS high availability so no custom software would be required (or necessary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Dataproc has a *high availability* (HA) mode built into the service. In HA mode, Cloud Dataproc clusters support both [HDFS High Availability](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html) and [YARN High Availability](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerHA.html) and both components are configured to allow uninterrupted YARN and HDFS operations despite any single-node failures/reboots.

There are a few important things to keep in mind about Cloud Dataproc HA mode:

- The HA feature is currently in beta
- All nodes use [Apache Zookeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org) for failover
- Jobs submitted through the Cloud Dataproc Jobs API are not considered "high availability" and will still be terminated on failure of the master node that runs the corresponding job driver programs

For more information on Cloud Dataproc HA mode, [see the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/high-availability). The documentation also provides instructions on how to submit work to the cluster outside of the Jobs tools/API.